# Как удалить элементы массива

Tags: php

Я получаю данные из БД в формате json
с помощью вот этого кода

```
$row=$dbconnection->prepare ("select * from  fa");
$row->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$row->execute();

$data=array();

foreach ($row as $result) {
    $data['movies'][] = $result;
}

echo json_encode ($data);   
?>
```

что я получил  `{"movies":[{"name":"212","0":"212"}]}`
что я хочу получить `{"movies":[{"name":"212"}]}` как удалить "0":"212"
в бд есть только 1 запись name=212

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы используете `ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE`. Он устанавливает режим выборки данных по умолчанию. А по умолчанию используется `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` (что равносильно `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`). В свою очередь `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` возвращает массив, индексированный именами столбцов результирующего набора, **а также их номерами (начиная с 0)**

Comment: Да у меня там ошибка Но я ещё не разобрался 
Warning: PDOStatement::setAttribute() [pdostatement.setattribute]: SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: This driver doesn't support setting attributes 
приедем показывает результат. неважно с ошибкой я сам разберусь

Comment: а  на что изменить ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE ? из-за ошибки эту строку вообще удалил но результат не изменился.

Comment: Надо оставить либо PDO::FETCH_OBJ либо PDO::FETCH_ASSOC (для ассоциативного массива). Скорее всего второе, т.к. потом вы делаете json_encode

Comment: "Driver does not support this function" --- некоторые СУБД не поддерживают работу с этим....например oracle

Comment: понятно а по-другому реализовать нельзя?

Comment: по-другому реализовать что?

Comment: удаление лишнего массива     ` $row->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ` не  помогло

Comment: Вы мой ответ прочитайте **внимательно** и поймёте в чём проблема